# How to bind/teardown events from a navigation bar to the controller in the current route?

Tags: ember.js

Coming from the Backbone world the last several years, I wanted to experiment with Ember. I figure I should try creating a mobile-web app, since I've done a lot of work in the mobile web w/ Backbone. I'm trying to build a global nav bar which has a Save button that shows up on certain routes, and the problem I'm stuck on is how to bind/teardown that click event on the Save button in the nav bar to the controller of the current route.

I have a `/routines/new` route where the app will show the user a form to create a new routine. The navigation bar extends `Ember.Evented` and propagates the click event via the `trigger` call. In my `App.RoutinesNewRoute`, within the `didTransition`/`willTransition` events I'm manually doing the binding from `App.NavigationController` to my `App.RoutinesNewController` (which contains the logic of how to save the model).

My current approach works, but this means in every route I'll have to manually do the binding/teardown, and it seems like a lot of boilerplate. I'm also envisioning controllers/components that can take advantage of this automatic binding/teardown process that have no direct relationship with the current route (i.e. controllers being inserted via `render` calls in the templates). I *feel* like there should be event that I can hook into where the controller "comes into view" so I can write the binding/teardown in one place and not have to think about it, but maybe I'm not understanding the "Ember" way.

So my question: **what's the best way to bind/teardown events from a global controller (i.e. nav bar) to any arbitrary controller that's backing the current views in DOM?**

---

Below is the code:

Right now, I have a `App.NavigationController` and an `App.NavigationView` that gets rendered into the application layout:

Navigation Controller

```
App.NavigationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend Ember.Evented,
  isShowing: false
  showBack: false
  title: ""
  rightButtonTitle: ""

  navigationStyle: (->
    if @get('isShowing')
      ""
    else
      "display: none;"
  ).property('isShowing')

  backStyle: (->
    if @get('showBack')
      ""
    else
      "display: none;"
  ).property('showBack')

  rightButtonStyle: (->
    if @get('rightButtonTitle')
      ""
    else
      "display:none"
  ).property('rightButtonTitle')

  actions:
    rightButtonClick: ->
      @trigger 'right-button'
    backButtonClick: ->
      @trigger 'back-button'
    reset: ->
      @setProperties
        isShowing: false
        title: ""
        rightButtonTitle: ""
```

App.NavigationView:

```
App.NavigationView = Ember.View.extend
  templateName: 'navigation'
  actions:
    rightButtonClick: ->
      @get('controller').send('rightButtonClick')
    backButtonClick: ->
      @get('controller').send('backButtonClick')
```

application.hbs

```
{{render 'navigation'}}
{{outlet}}
```

App.RoutinesNewRoute

```
App.RoutinesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    if routine = @controllerFor('application').get('routine')
      routine
    else
      @store.find('routine').then (routines) =>
        nextDay = routines.content.length + 1

        promise = @store.find('exercise').then (exercises) =>
          exercises = exercises.map (e) ->
            id: e.get('id')
            name: e.get('name')
            weight: e.get('weight')

          routine = @store.createRecord 'routine',
            exercises: exercises
            day: nextDay

          @controllerFor('application').set('routine', routine)
          routine


  actions:
    didTransition: ->
      @_super()
      # This is where I do all the manual event binding
      @controllerFor('navigation').on 'right-button', @, =>
        @controller.save().then =>
          @controllerFor('application').set('routine', null)
        @transitionTo('routines')

      @controllerFor('navigation').on 'back-button', @, =>
        @transitionTo('routines')

      @controllerFor('navigation').setProperties
        isShowing: true
        showBack: true
        title: "New Routine"
        rightButtonTitle: "Save"


    willTransition: ->
      # This is where I do all the manual event teardown
      @_super()
      @controllerFor('navigation').off 'right-button', @
      @controllerFor('navigation').off 'back-button', @
      @controllerFor('navigation').send('reset')
```

App.RoutinesNewController

```
App.RoutinesNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  save: -> @get('model').save()

  actions:
    save: -> @save()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is extract the "save through navigation" behavior in a mixin. I'm not very familiar with CoffeeScript so the following is a mix of Javascript and CoffeeScript.

```
App.SaveableThroughNavigationMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
  doEventBindings: function() {
    @_super()
    # This is where I do all the manual event binding
    @controllerFor('navigation').on 'right-button', @, =>
      @controller.save().then =>
        @controllerFor('application').set('routine', null)
      @transitionTo('routines')

    @controllerFor('navigation').on 'back-button', @, =>
      @transitionTo('routines')

    @controllerFor('navigation').setProperties
      isShowing: true
      showBack: true
      title: "New Routine"
      rightButtonTitle: "Save"
  }.on('didTransition'),
  doEventTeardowns: function() {
    # This is where I do all the manual event teardown
    @_super()
    @controllerFor('navigation').off 'right-button', @
    @controllerFor('navigation').off 'back-button', @
    @controllerFor('navigation').send('reset')
  }.on('willTransition')
});
```

Then for every `Route` that you want this behavior, you include the mixin.

```
App.RoutinesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.SaveableThroughNavigationMixin, {
  model: function() {
    ...
  }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok my mistake. What if you try to rename `doEventBindings` and `doEventTeardowns` to `didTransition` and `willTransition`, and putting them in an `actions` hash?

Comment: I ended up overriding the `activate` and `deactivate` methods and calling `@_super()` within them. While the documentation says `activate`/`deactivate` won't be called when the model changes, it seems to work for me (Ember 1.7.0).